# Is there a standard way to cache doctrine objects?

Tags: php, caching, doctrine-orm, symfony

Suppose I have many objects with attributes that rarely change. I don't want the DB being hit all the time to fetch the data for those objects. What can I do?

Answer (score 4):

Doctrine2 offers [query](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.1/en/reference/caching.html#query-cache) and [result caching](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.1/en/reference/caching.html#result-cache).

The caching relies on third party caching solutions like APC, Memcache and Xcache. Doctrine offers drivers to integrate those into your application.